# Have Hyperdoctrines been formalized?

Tags: coq, reference-request, software-request

I was thinking of formalizing them myself for a project if they haven't been already, and I looked in libraries and couldn't find anything.

I was thinking of coq in particular because it's the only proof assistant I've used in the past, but if they've been formalized elsewhere, I'm interested too.

Also, if someone has general advice for where to look for libraries in general, I definitely appreciate it. In this case I was looking [in this page](https://github.com/uhub/awesome-coq) but there doesn't seem to be anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If someone else, like me, was wondering: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hyperdoctrine